# How to catch a NumberFormatException for a property in Spring-Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, numberformatexception

I have the following property:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApp implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Value("${numberOfDocs:10}")
    private int numberOfDocuments;
```

Is there a way to catch the NumberFormatException , if my user, in spite of all the warnings and instructions, decides to put a non-integer value for this variable in application.properties?

I can't just put a try-catch block around this variable. So what are my other options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could also use @Value as parameter with setter injection:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApp implements CommandLineRunner {


    private int numberOfDocuments;

    @Autowired
    public void setValues(@Value("${numberOfDocs:10}") String numberOfDocuments) {
        try this.numberOfDocuments=Integer.parseInt(numberOfDocuments);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            this.numberOfDocuments=10;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definetely make a custom constructor that takes the argument as `String` and does your custom logic:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsoleApp implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Value("${numberOfDocs:10}")
    private int numberOfDocuments;

    public ConsoleApp(@Value("${numberOfDocs:10}") String numberOfDocuments){
        try{
            this.numberOfDocuments=Integer.parseInt(numberOfDocuments);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            this.numberOfDocuments=10;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I have removed the lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` because I used a custom constructor.